# Fortran in MatLab - Error in mex Setup

Tags: matlab, mex

I am trying to use a .F90 file, calling it from an m-file. From the little I've read, I am supposed to use this mex setup to get things going. I have installed Intel Parallel Studio 2015 and Windows SDK 8. Now from the error below, I suspect that MatLab is not looking for the more recent versions. Anyways, how can I get the mex setup to work?

Here is the error code:

```
mex -setup -v
Verbose mode is on.
... Looking for compiler 'Intel C++ Composer XE 2011 with Microsoft SDK 7.1 (C)' ...
... Looking for environment variable 'ICPP_COMPILER12' ...No.
Did not find installed compiler 'Intel C++ Composer XE 2011 with Microsoft SDK 7.1 (C)'.
... Looking for compiler 'Intel C++ Composer XE 2011 with Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 (C)' ...
... Looking for environment variable 'ICPP_COMPILER12' ...No.
Did not find installed compiler 'Intel C++ Composer XE 2011 with Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 (C)'.
... Looking for compiler 'Intel C++ Composer XE 2011 with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 (C)' ...
... Looking for environment variable 'ICPP_COMPILER12' ...No.
Did not find installed compiler 'Intel C++ Composer XE 2011 with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 (C)'.
... Looking for compiler 'Intel C++ Composer XE 2013 with Microsoft SDK 7.1' ...
... Looking for environment variable 'ICPP_COMPILER14' ...No.
... Looking for environment variable 'ICPP_COMPILER13' ...No.
Did not find installed compiler 'Intel C++ Composer XE 2013 with Microsoft SDK 7.1'.
... Looking for compiler 'Intel C++ Composer XE 2013 with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 (C)' ...
... Looking for environment variable 'ICPP_COMPILER14' ...No.
... Looking for environment variable 'ICPP_COMPILER13' ...No.
Did not find installed compiler 'Intel C++ Composer XE 2013 with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 (C)'.
... Looking for compiler 'Intel C++ Composer XE 2013 with Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 (C)' ...
... Looking for environment variable 'ICPP_COMPILER14' ...No.
... Looking for environment variable 'ICPP_COMPILER13' ...No.
Did not find installed compiler 'Intel C++ Composer XE 2013 with Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 (C)'.
... Looking for compiler 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 (C)' ...
... Looking for environment variable 'VS90COMNTOOLS' ...No.
Did not find installed compiler 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 (C)'.
... Looking for compiler 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 (C)' ...
... Looking for environment variable 'VS100COMNTOOLS' ...No.
Did not find installed compiler 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 (C)'.
... Looking for compiler 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 (C)' ...
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7' 11.0 ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7' 11.0 ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7' 11.0 ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKCU\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7' 11.0 ...No.
Did not find installed compiler 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 (C)'.
... Looking for compiler 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Professional (C)' ...
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7' 12.0 ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7' 12.0 ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7' 12.0 ...Yes ('C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\').
... Looking for file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\amd64\cl.exe' ...No.
Did not find installed compiler 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Professional (C)'.
... Looking for compiler 'Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1 (C)' ...
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1' InstallationFolder ...No.
Did not find installed compiler 'Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1 (C)'.
```

Thanks.

EDIT: I have installed Windows SDK 7.1 and managed to run `mex -setup`:

```
mex -setup
MEX configured to use 'Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1 (C)' for C language compilation.
Warning: The MATLAB C and Fortran API has changed to support MATLAB
     variables with more than 2^32-1 elements. In the near future
     you will be required to update your code to utilize the
     new API. You can find more information about this at:
     http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/upgrading-mex-files-to-use-64-bit-api.html.
```

However, when clicking to choose Fortran language, I get:

```
To choose a different language, select one from the following:
 mex -setup C++ 
 mex -setup FORTRAN
Error using mex
No supported compiler or SDK was found. For options, visit 
http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2014b/win64.html.
```

Comment: Which matlab version are you using? It seems earching SDK 7.1, check the documentation for compatible compiler.

Comment: You are most likely using a version of MATLAB that doesn't support your compiler.  From the looks of it, your compiler is **too new**.  As what Daniel said, what version of MATLAB are you using?  There is a list of supported compilers per MATLAB version.

Comment: @user191919 - MATLAB R2014b only supports Windows SDK 7.1 - http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2014b/index.html - As I suspected, you're using a compiler that is too new.  You'll need to downgrade to SDK 7.1 if you want to compile stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install Windows SDK 7.1 or one of the other compilers listed [in the documentation](http://de.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2014b/index.html). Notice the differences between 32 bit and 64 bit.

Comment: Pretty much what I said! + 1.

Comment: I get an error when trying to install SDK 7.1, probably because I have Windows 8 (duh). Do you see any way out?

Comment: @user191919 - http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101105-how-do-i-install-microsoft-windows-sdk-7-1

Comment: Ok, made some progress but not quite there yet. See my edit please.

Comment: Solved the issue, thanks. I installed Intel Parallel Studio 2013.